# Text effect on C#

Tags: c#

I would like to ask what is the code for this text effect on C# when for example, I have this PROTECT YOUR COMPUTER title, then, when I point my cursor on it, it should be underlined, and when I click it, the contents inside it should be shown below the title. It is commonly used in Help and Support Section when your using Windows.

Thanks in advance! and Sorry for my english.

Comment: Is this for WinForms, WebForms, or WPF?

Comment: WinForms sir. by the way what's WPF?

Comment: @eljay : WPF :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the LinkLabel control.